# Interfacing three UART devices to Microcontroller without loss of data

Tags: microcontroller, communication, uart, embedded, tm4c123g

I have a microcontroller TM4C123GXL Launchpad, that has 8 serial UART ports. I am using Keil uVision5 with  Tiva Ware for programming.

I wanted to interface 3 UART devices with the microcontroller without any loss of bytes. The baud rate has been set to 115200 bits/sec with no parity as shown in the figure below. All devices sent data frame periodically every **5ms.**

[image: Communication system]

TX and RX time are calculated using No_0f_bytes*10/BaudRate

I have successfully interfaced the devices with the UART of µC. 
The problem in the communication is that that I am losing the bytes. If I do a communication with a single device (Device 2) I am still losing the bytes from the whole frame (20 bytes).

Is it due to the 16 byte FIFO limitation of Tm4c123 or anything else?

I have also implemented the µDMA feature of TM4C123. But still, bytes are lost.
What can I do to improve the system for lossless transmission and reception of data frames?

**Edit:**

Here is the Software Architecture:

I am using Periodic Timer Interrupt of 5ms to receive and transmit the frame.
All frame has first 2 bytes header and a counter byte as the last byte.

```
void Timer1IntHandler(void) //  Periodic Service Routine every 5ms
{

DisableIntrupts();

bool Correct=ReadJoystick(); //10 bytes  Device 1

if(Correct)
{
GenerateServoCardsFrame();

SendServo1Frame();   //20 bytes  Device 2
SendServo2Frame(); //17 bytes  Device 3
ReadServo1Frame();  //15 bytes Device 2
ReadServo2Frame();  //20 bytes Device 3

GenerateJoystickFrame();

SendJoystickFrame(); //10 bytes   Device 1

EnableIntrupts();
}

}

main()
{
SetupClock()  ;   //Setup 16 MHz Clock
SetupJoystick();  //Initalize uart1 port for Device1
SetupServoCard1(); //Initalize uart2 port for Device2
SetupServoCard2(); //Initalize uart3 port for Device3

InitalizePeriodicTimerHandler(5);   //Periodic Service Routine every 5ms  (Timer1IntHandler)

while(1)
{
}

}


bool ReadJoystick(void)
{
    int BytePos=0;
    int CountInvalid=0;
    int LoopoutTime=0;

    while(1)
    {
    if (ROM_UARTCharsAvail(UART1))                              
        { 
            ByteRX = ROM_UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART1);            
            if (BytePos==0)
            {
                if (ByteRX== 0xA1)      //Header1 found                              
                {
                    KArray[0] = Bytebuf ;
                    BytePos ++;
                }
                else
                {
                    CountInvalid++;
                    if (CountInvalid>5) 
                        return 0;
                }           
            }            
            else if (BytePos ==1) 
            {           
                if (ByteRX == 0x66)      //Header2 found                                   
                {   
                    KArray[1] = ByteRX;
                    BytePos ++;
                }
                else                                                   
                    BytePos=0;                                                        
            }            
            else
            {
                KArray[BytePos++] = ByteRX;                
                if (BytePos==10)                                                      
                    return 1;      //Frame Recived                                                   
            }
        }
        else                                                          
        {
            SysCtlDelay(0.25*SysCtlClockGet()/3 / 1000);        //   0.25ms delay
            LoopoutTime++;            
            if (LoopoutTime > 10)                                      
                return 0;            
        }    
    }       

}
```

According to my calculation, 1 byte requires 10/115200=0.08680ms and to read a FIFO of 16 bytes requires 1.38ms.  The table in the figure shows total Tx time of 4.08ms and Rx time of 3.91 ms which sums to 8ms. This is greater than my Periodic Interrupt Service Routine.

**Do I have to increase the Periodic Interrupt Timing?**

Comment: did you try this in a lower baud rate ? Higher baud rates means more error prone.

Comment: Devices can't be configured for lower baud rate. Only Baudrate of 115200 bits/sec is compatible.

Comment: what device is that ?

Comment: One is a Joy Stick and other Two are servo controller card. 
Their firmware is set by someone else.

Comment: Yea 16 byte fifo is small. That would be the reason.

Comment: Bytes incoming through a UART get lost when the UART driver software does not service the UART fast enough.  You haven't provided enough details about your software for anyone to provide detailed suggestions.  Generally, I would suggest you need a more responsive software design or a faster CPU clock.

Comment: You would have to read every byte so fast (roughly every 64 microseconds for baudrate 115200)

Comment: @MasoodSalik I've written UART drivers for the 16C554 chip a long time ago. These have 16-byte FIFOs and are quad devices so there are four ports. I used data rates exactly the same as you mentioned, as well. And all of this was running well with a very old and slow micro (the 4.77 MHz 8088.) Never lost a single byte... ever. It all just works. If you are having a problem, then it is either buried in some code you didn't write (a library routine you are making incorrect assumptions about) or else a mistake in what you are writing. If your external devices work, there is no other way to see it.

Comment: @MasoodSalik The ONLY way a 20-byte frame is trouble is if you are VERY LAZY in your coding and make your software sit there doing nothing while the communications are taking place. Rather, your software ***must*** be active in removing bytes from the FIFO (and there are a number of ways to approach this: start draining at "half-full" is just one example) while the communications are taking place. I don't know anything about your TM4C123GXL, but FIFO-backed ports almost always have different "trigger levels" you can select, as appropriate (first-in, half-full, or full, to name three.) Use one.

Comment: @MasoodSalik See section "14.3.8 FIFO Operation" of the [TM4C123GXL Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf). Note: (1) "*Out of reset, both FIFOs are disabled*," and (2) "*FIFOs can be individually configured to trigger interrupts at different levels. Available configurations include ⅛, ¼, ½, ¾, and ⅞.*" For receive, I'd probably go with either ½ or ¾, depending. You really need to read the datasheet and to get control over your receiver coding. Your external devices and TI MCU are fine. Are you using this site as a way to avoid having to read and think for yourself?

Comment: I have updated the question with Software Architecture. A Periodic Interrupt Service read and transmit the frame.  @jonk I have gone through the datasheet of TM4C123GXL.  If we use Interrupt for receiving the bytes then we can define the Interrupt Fifo level. I  also have configured the uC using Interrupt but the problem in it was that Continuously Interrupt Service Routine was called, though no data was on a serial bus.

Comment: @MasoodSalik It's got to work if you have the code written correctly. I have no question about that. I've done this kind of thing so many times in the past. I'm certain the device ASIC (MCU) is designed correctly so that programmers can do this properly. This isn't the kind of mistake you see made by IC designers. You are probably thinking that the interrupt you are getting is related, when it is arriving for a different reason that you aren't dealing properly with. The boards are only US$13 and I have one ordered yesterday. It'll be easy to test. But you'll have to wait a few weeks.

Comment: I have been on it for 4 months. Have tried different possibilities but failed. Datasheet says UART is similar to a 16C550. The page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART says "The original 16550 had a bug that prevented this FIFO from being used. N.S later released the 16550A which corrected this issue. Not all manufacturers adopted this nomenclature, however, continuing to refer to the fixed chip as a 16550
According to another source, the FIFO issue was corrected only in the 16550AF model, with the A model still being buggy. (The C and CF models are okay too, according to this source.) "

Comment: @MasoodSalik Sure, I had to deal with a variety of silicon bugs in the past, including those on some of the 16550's. But none of that applies here. This is a modern device and based upon decades of prior experience. I'm pretty confident that it just works as documented. But I'll know soon enough. You can look up the TI Errata on the device, too. Double check that (as I will have to, soon.) TI generally does NOT fix silicon bugs, but instead documents them. (Microchip actually fixes them, often.)

Comment: @MasoodSalik Start here: [Tiva C Series TM4C123x Microcontrollers, Silicon Revisions 6 and 7, Silicon Errata](http://www.ti.com/lit/er/spmz849f/spmz849f.pdf). Search for "Uart" and see what you find there. It also won't hurt to look up the ARM errata, as well: [ARM Cortex-M4F Errata (v3)](http://www.ti.com/lit/er/spmz637/spmz637.pdf). But it's not likely to be much help, as that is about the processor, instead.

Comment: @MasoodSalik If it's not clear by now, you *must* do your research on any device. In this case, it means studying the MCU errata (from ARM), the ASIC errata (from TI), and the LaunchPad errata (also from TI, but found separately in the doc on the board.) You must also carefully study all of the details regarding the port setup, timers, and pretty much everything found in the nearly 1,500 page Datasheet. You've spend 4 months with this, you say. I would have spent the first week (or two) before writing ONE LINE of code, studying these documents carefully. Did you do that?

Comment: In this case it would seem like poor programming is to blame, however. This is not how you write ISRs - there is way too much code, the interrupt latency will be horrible. And then obvious find-in-5-seconds bugs, such as the interrupt getting permanently shut off. I can also pretty much guarantee that you have missing `volatile` bugs all over. The form of `main` used is from the dinosaur era, which suggests that a bad compiler is used. And so on.

Comment: @jonk I have gone through the documents you listed. There is a silicon bug which is not related to me. I haven't gone through datasheet much since I am using Tiva Ware Driver Peripheral Library, which automatically handles the register level programming. And i work once a week.
Lundin: Have understood the point that not to write a long subroutine in ISR.

Comment: @MasoodSalik Glad to hear an update. Thanks. I've been using MCUs since long before you were born, I am sure (about 40 years already.) In that time, I have *often* written code to handle multiple, 16-byte FIFO channels -- external as well as internal to MCUs. These have included silicon bugs, at times. In every single case, I've been able to make them work flawlessly. But I wrote my own code, did my own research and work, and using that info developed appropriate code. If you use a library, then you depend on the work of others and if there is a problem you should contact them, I suppose.

Comment: Yes. Sure.
 TivaWare™ is by Texas Instrument and designed to simplify and speed the development process that's why I am using it.  There were bugs in my software architecture. Now I have established successful communication between the 2 devices. Will soon experiments with multiple devices.

Comment: @MasoodSalik Good to hear. Software designed to help people "get started quickly" isn't often the best software, but instead just something created to help their field representatives working with customers quickly show a customer that the problem is in the customer's software and not in the manufacturer's hardware. It often doesn't solve anything but the most trivial end-use needs. I never use such software except to cross-check myself, knowing it will be of very limited real value. And yes, it is usually a matter of bugs in what you write. That's been my experience.

Comment: @MasoodSalik Usually, I break up my driver code into four pieces with two buffers to mediate. There is the receiver driver consisting of a high level interface for the rest of my code and a low level interface for the hardware, with a buffer between them. And the same concept, repeated, for the transmit side. The buffers decouple the higher level use from the lower level hardware support side. You can add buffer pool management, if you want to get tricky. Or else supply statically allocated buffers on a permanent basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your software design is not good and is probably the reason that incoming bytes are being lost.

First, I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a typo.  You disable interrupts at the beginning of `Timer1IntHandler()` but then you only re-enable interrupts if `Correct` is true.  Don't you want to re-enable interrupts before returning regardless of the conditional?  It seems strange that interrupts could be left disabled when the function returns.

It appears that your code reads characters from UART1 only within the `ReadJoystick()` function.  And I suspect that UART1 is not read while all those functions from `GenerateServoCardsFrame()` to `SendJoystickFrame()` are called.  How long does it take for those functions to run?  Could those functions take long enough for the UART1 FIFO to fill up and overflow?  This could be when incoming bytes are getting dropped.

If I was designing this software I would implement it completely differently than what you have done.  I would enable the UART interrupt request and create a quick UART interrupt handler routine.  The only thing the UART ISR would do is to copy bytes to/from the UART TX/RX registers.  I would create two circular (a.k.a. ring) buffers to hold the bytes.  The UART ISR would copy a recieved byte from the UART RX register to the RX circular buffer.  And the UART ISR would copy a byte to transmit from the TX circular buffer to the UART TX register.  The UART ISR would not attempt to interpret the meaning of any of the bytes.  All it does is move bytes between the RAM buffers and the UART peripheral.  This keeps the UART ISR short, which allows the overall program to be more response to other interrupts.

Then I would create a `main()` function with an infinite loop and within the infinite loop I would call a function called `SerialReceive()` to read messages out of the RX buffer.  `SerialReceive()` would be implemented as a state machine.  If any bytes are available in the RX buffer then it will process a finite number of bytes through the state machine.  The state machine would have states for the frame header, body and trailer similar to what you've done.  `SerialReceive()` returns immediately when either a message is completed or no more bytes are available.  When a message is incomplete because no more bytes are immediately available then `SerialReceive()` won't wait for them, instead it will remember the current state and message so that it can continue with the same message when it is called again from `main()`.

If you need to do something periodically then setup a timer like you have done, but rather than doing all the work within the timer ISR, just set a flag instead.  The main infinite loop should repeatedly check the flag and do whatever is appropriate when the flag has been set by the timer ISR.  Doing the work from the context of `main()` means that the system can respond to other interrupts while it is doing the work.

Keeping ISRs short allows the overall system to be more responsive to other interrupt requests.  If you spend too much time in an ISR, like I believe you are doing in your timer ISR, then the system will not be responsive.

**Update:**
In your comment you say that those functions loop until transmits are complete and they take over 7 milliseconds.  That's enough time for 80 bytes to arrive at the UART and your code is not reading those bytes during this time so of course bytes will be lost.

Your transmitting functions should copy bytes into the TX buffer and return without waiting for the entire message to be transmitted.  The UART ISR should transmit one byte each invocation while the TX buffer contains bytes.

The RX and TX buffer should be larger than any message.  Typically the buffers are a power-of-two in size because that makes it easy to circle the buffer pointers around back to the beginning.  So make them 256 bytes (or 128 or 64, but why not bigger?).

You should have an independent set of RX/TX buffers for each UART.

Changing the period of your periodic timer ISR is not going to affect the problem with your original code.  Within your periodic ISR, your code is spending 7 milliseconds *NOT* reading the UART.  Your code is going to lose bytes regardless of the timer period.

Comment: The Ending Brace was a typo while writing the pseudocode.  My UART Transmitting functions are made such a may that until all the bytes are sent, it will remain in the loop. So for sending 20 bytes its costs 1.74ms. All all the function in a "if" loop takes 7.11ms. 
Does i have to increase the Periodic ISR timing?

I have succesfully implemented a cicular buffer to store the UART recived bytes using an intrupt. And checking the flag in the while loop in main(). Its working fine with a single device. Will soon experiment with 2 devices.
What circullar buffer size shoud i set? 2x data bytes?

Comment: Should the Circular buffer size be double than the actual frame?

Comment: @MasoodSalik, I updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: Does there exist any concept that once I call a function, The function calls itself after some time (calculated) until some condition is reached; without making the system idle.  I wanted to implement it for transmitting function. Once I fill the Tx Fifo, function again calls itself after some time and refill the FIFO until the whole frame is sent.

Comment: @MasoodSalik you are thinking about it wrong.  Instead of calculating when you can refill, let the UART inform you when you can refill.  More specifically, enable the appropriate UART IRQ so that the UART ISR is called when bytes can be added to the FIFO.  Honestly, I don't think you should be trying to use the UART FIFO until you get it working without the FIFO.  And I strongly recommend you look for example code online.  My answer is an overview and leaves out important details that are going to trip you up.